# How to efficiently find the indices a first array values matching with a second array values?

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have two numpy arrays A and B. A has shape `(10000000, 3)` and B has shape `(1000000, 3)`. Both the arrays are XYZ coordinates such that B corresponds to some region of A. I have to find indexes of A which correspond to values B.
Right now I am solving as below. I would like some help in optimizing this using Numpy or other python packages.

```py
extract_BinA=np.empty(B.shape[0])
for i in range(B.shape[0]):
    for j in range(A.shape[0]):
        if(A[j][0]==B[i][0] and A[j][1]==B[i][1] and A[j][2]==B[i][2]):
            extract_BinA[i]=j
```

Comment: Those are huge arrays- as you have discovered, the two for loop approach won't scale. To develop a better approach we need to know more, like how many elements will you want to subsample, and are the arrays sparse ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I want to get all the indexes corresponding to B. Arrays are dense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is not the speed of pure-python code, but the **algorithm** itself. You can use **sorted-arrays** or **hash-tables** to improve the complexity of the algorithm to `O(n log n)` or even `O(n)` rather than the slow current `O(n^2)` solution (as well as the solution proposed by @Mazen). An `O(n^2)` cannot be efficient here since it will results in roughly `10,000,000 * 10,000,000 = 100,000 billion operations` which is too much for any modern computer.

Here is a hash-table solution in pure Python:

```py
table = {tuple(A[i]):i for i in range(A.shape[0])}
extract_BinA = np.empty(B.shape[0])
for i in range(B.shape[0]):
    val = tuple(B[i])
    if val in table:
        extract_BinA[i] = table[val]
```

Note that the result may differ if there are multiple points in the same location in `A`.

Here is a benchmark with two random array of size 10,000:

```
Initial solution: 53.82 s
Mazen solution:    1.76 s
This solution:     0.02 s
```

On this small input, the above code is **2700 times faster** than the initial solution and 88 times faster than the proposed alternative solution. On bigger input, the gap will be much bigger and the above code is many order of magnitude faster than the two other solutions  (ie. >10000 times faster).

---

### Update:

If there are multiple points equal each other in `A`, then the dictionary can be modified to store list of indices rather than one value. Alternatively, the dictionary can be created so that the first value is kept like in the original code. Here are example of the two solutions:

```py
table = dict()
for i in range(A.shape[0])
    key = tuple(A[i])
    if key in table:
        table[key].append(i)
    else:
        table[key] = [i]

extract_BinA = np.empty(B.shape[0])
for i in range(B.shape[0]):
    val = tuple(B[i])
    if val in table:
        # Here table[val] is a list and thus you 
        # can do whatever you want with the indices. 
        # For example you can take the first one like here, 
        # or possibly the last as you want.
        extract_BinA[i] = table[val][0]
```

```py
# Select always directly the first index
table = dict()
for i in range(A.shape[0])
    key = tuple(A[i])
    if key not in table:
        table[key] = i

extract_BinA = np.empty(B.shape[0])
for i in range(B.shape[0]):
    val = tuple(B[i])
    if val in table:
        extract_BinA[i] = table[val]
```

Note that these solution are a bit slower than the above code but the complexity is still linear (and thus still very fast).

Comment: Your answer makes sense and I think it is better. OP, could you set this answer as the right answer for your problem.

Comment: your solution using  A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15]])
B = np.array([[0,0,0],[4,5,6],[13,14,15]]) is  [1. 1. 4.]  so there I am missing something why 1 is there twice ?

Comment: How to modify this code to get all the indexes if there are multiple points at the same location. There are many such points.

Comment: @pippo1980 One should be careful as I use `np.empty` like the OP did. If there is no value written, then the value is undefined. I got the same problem the first time I tested the code. However, the original code do that too, so I just reproduced the same behavior. When initialized with `np.ones(B.shape[0]) * -1` the result is the same for the three methods.

Comment: Ok Jerome , thanks a lot for your time 

Comment: @nhm I edited the answer to provide examples covering this case

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thanks for the solution and quick reply. I have one more question. Actually I am trying to compare and extract floats. So it's not working as expected. How to solve it.

Comment: @nhm Comparing floats using a strict equality is generally rather a [bad idea](https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/). You may need a method based on distances if you do not have exactly the same points. The thing is that using a distance based approach make the problem much more complex and so the solutions. The usual approach is to use an [octree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) in your case which can solve this in `O(n log(n))`. Alternatively, you can still use the hashmap with rounding if you know that numbers are accurate with a (quite low) bounded error margin.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yes, numbers are accurate with errors of less than 1e-6.

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

```py
extract_BinA = np.ones(B.shape[0]) * -1
for i, b in enumerate(B):
    idx = np.argwhere((A == b) == [True, True, True])
    if idx.any():
        extract_BinA[i] = idx[0][0]
print(extract_BinA)
```

## Explanation

Set `extract_BinA` to negative values array of size B

> extract_BinA = np.ones(B.shape[0]) * -1

In order to get the indices of the elements where B elements equals to A elements, we would need to do the following:

> (A == b)

Compares x,y,z for a row in B with every x,y,z rows in A

> (A == b) == [True, True, True]

Compares only elements where x_a==x_b, y_a==y_b, and z_a==z_b yields True for all of them

> np.argwhere((A == b) == [True, True, True])

Returns a set of indices where the condition is true

## A full example to test:

```py
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15]])
B = np.array([[0,0,0],[4,5,6],[13,14,15]])
# your code
extract_BinA=np.ones(B.shape[0]) * -1
for i in range(B.shape[0]):
    for j in range(A.shape[0]):
        if (A[j] == B[i]).all():
            extract_BinA[i]=j
print(extract_BinA)
# my code
extract_BinA = np.ones(B.shape[0]) * -1
for i, b in enumerate(B):
    idx = np.argwhere((A == b) == [True, True, True])
    if idx.any():
        extract_BinA[i] = idx[0][0] -----------> changed  extract_BinB to  extract_BinA
print(extract_BinA)
```